# Filtering MySQL data to JTable

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a table in my `SQL` in the following structure called student:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| studentno | lastname  | firstname | middlename |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 2001-0001 | Matrix    | John      |    G       | 
| 2001-0002 | Mata      | Evan      |    A       | 
| 2001-0003 | Melly     | Carmelo   |    P       |
| 2001-0004 | Hamburger | Hardy     |    P       |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

I have a `JTable` and a `JTextField` in my Java Program. What I would like to do is, if I type letter M (case insensitive) in the `JTextField`, all the student who's last name starts with letter `M` will display on my `JTable`. If I type a second letter, say for example, `A`, all the students who's last name starts with `MA` will display, until I got a specific last name on my `JTable`..

*My problem is that, even though I type letter `M`, all of the data in my `MA`appears on my `JTable` instead of just all the students who's last name starts with letter `M`..
And my `JTable` doesn't clears up even if I empty my `JTextField`..*

I am using `Netbeans` and so far I have this code in my `JTextFieldKeyPressed`:

```
private void lastNameKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    


  Connection conn = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "students_dbs";
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String databaseUserName = "user1";
    String databasePassword = "test";
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Connected to the database.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Failed to connect ot the database.");
    }


try{
String sql = "SELECT studentno, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM student WHERE lastname LIKE '%" + lastname.getText() + "%'";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
result = pst.executeQuery();
studentsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(result));
}
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add a listener to Listen for changes in the text, then send that text to your query to retrieve new data based on the passed text.

```
// Listen for changes in the text
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warn();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warn();
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warm();
  }

  public void warn() {
     // fire the execute statement.
  }
});
```

then you need to change your query to something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT studentno, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM student WHERE firstname= '" + jtextfield.getText() + "%'";
```

Comment: thank you! i actually use netbeans, so instead of using KeyPressed, I have used KeyReleased. Which I think is similar concept to DocumentListener that you have suggested. and for my query, I have omitted the first `%` which gave me this query. `String sql = "SELECT studentno, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM student WHERE firstname LIKE '" + jtextfield.getText() + "%'";`